# Implementing a model without a flatten layer in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

A typical approach using CNNs consists of the convolutional part and the fully connected layers part which are connected with a flatten layer. This layer transforms the output of the conv. part (of a shape `(x, y, z)`) into a 1D feature vector which is past to the classifier consisting of the fully connected layers.

My problem is finding just one pixel in the image which is a center of some object, while the topology/texture of the whole image leads to this point. So I'd like to have a model, which doesn't have the flatten layer, instead the FC part takes individual vectors from the output of conv. part and the output of the FC layers is the distance to this pixel of interest (I think that these individual feature vectors carry this information). The idea is easy, but how to train this? I'm wondering whether this could be implemented somehow in tensorflow (or any other framework)?

The other option is a typical model with the flatten layer. The FC part would take the whole output from the conv. part (the whole feature map) and it would predict the position of the wanted pixel. Do you think these two variants are equivalent? It'd be great as this second option is very easy to implement in any framework.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a segmentation problem, the only difference is that usual models predict the bounding box (4 floating values), while you wish to predict a single value (if that's what you mean by *distance*). But it's not crucial in terms of code, because it's just replacement of *classification head* with *regression head*. Both of your described methods seem to do the same.

Here's a sample code in tensorflow:

```py
# Assume:
#   layer.shape = (?, 16, 16, 64)   <- last CNV layer output
#   y.shape = (?, 1)                <- target distance

# FC layer params: will output (?, 128)
w_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16 * 16 * 64, 128]))
b_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128]))

# Output layer params: will output (?, 1)
w_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128, 1]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))

# Reshape to make applicable to the FC layer
reshaped = tf.reshape(layer, [-1, w_fc.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(reshaped, w_fc), b_fc)
fc = tf.nn.relu(fc)
out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc, w_out), b_out)

# Standard L2 loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(out - y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)
```